# Vulnerability TrustManager Google play

Tags: java, android-studio, google-play-console, android-manifest

estoy tratando de cambiar esta implementación debido a que google play la rechaza por que tiene una vulnerabilidad

```
@SuppressLint("TrulyRandom")
    private void trustAllHosts() {
        try {
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[0];
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509ExtendedTrustManager() {
                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, Socket socket) throws CertificateException {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, Socket socket) throws CertificateException {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, SSLEngine sslEngine) throws CertificateException {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, SSLEngine sslEngine) throws CertificateException {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {

                    }

                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return new X509Certificate[0];
                    }
                }};
            }

            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier((arg0, arg1) -> true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

El tema  es que es la unica que me funciona, ya he hecho muchas moodificaciones, e implemente el archivo network-security-config.xml y no me permite, pareciera que no aceptara dicha conexión o que de plano la rechaza

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

La idea es permitir cualquier trafico no certificado ya que el servidor del backeend no provee uno hasta donde tengo entendido o provee uno no seguro.

archivo manifest:

```
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="false"
```

Le agradezco cualquier ayuda, si no hago dicho cambio la google play quitara la aplicación

Comment: "Es la única que me funciona" .... a ver, que le estás diciendo que confíe en absolutamente cualquier ruta! Al menos cambia esto: `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier((arg0, arg1) -> true);` por una url válida o algo, limítalo un poco. Tal cual lo tienes lo que has hecho es deshabilitar completamente la seguridad de android

Comment: @Benito-B Si entiendo eso, el problema esta en el servidor no emite un certificado valido, pero el inconveniente es que yo no tengo control de ese servidor, por lo que es esta implementación la que permite la petición